# How to add CSS class to widget/field with Django 1.11 template-based form rendering

Tags: python, css, django, django-templates, django-widget

Note: This question shouldn't be conflated with past questions that are similar but before Django 1.11, when they released template-based form rendering.

I understand that Django now has template-based form rendering. From what I understand, this is supposed to fix the issue of having to inject CSS classes from the view or the form, rather than keeping all of the HTML/CSS in the templates.

That is my goal: to keep my forms and views focused on **what** is displayed, and my templates focused on **how** that is displayed. So I want to keep all HTML/CSS in my templates.

So, my questions are:

- How do I add a class (for example, `form-text`) to all `TextInput` widgets from the template system?
- How do I add a class (for example, `alert-warning`) to all error messages (validation failures) from the template system?

I may have misunderstood something about this new feature, so if I did, feel free to let me know if this isn't how it works or if I am asking the impossible. Ideally, I would like to implement these form rendering changes to the master template.

## Sample Problem

`views.py`:

```
class SignUp(generic.edit.CreateView):

    model = models.User
    template_name = 'usermgmt/sign_up.html'
    form_class = forms.UserCreateForm
    success_url = '/sign_up_done/'
```

`templates/master.html` (I want to put something in here that causes all `TextInput` widgets to get a class):

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} | Website</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="content-wrapper clearfix">
    {% block main %}{% endblock %}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`templates/usermgmt/sign_up.html`:

```
{% extends 'master.html' %}

{% block title %}Sign Up{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
<h1>Sign Up</h1>
<p>Enter your email to sign up!</p>
<form class="form-group" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I've understood from the [release notes of Django 1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.11/#template-based-widget-rendering) and from my own testing, the new features *only* allows us to easily customize the way widgets are rendered by simply providing HTML files for each widget type. In previous Django versions you had to provide a subclass of `forms.widget.Widget` and assign that widget to your model/form fields one by one (IIRC).

If you wanna make all `TextInput` widgets have a specific class, you're gonna have to add your custom `text.html` (and probably your own `attrs.html`  as well).

For example, let's say I have a `myforms` project with a `main` app. According to the docs:

> If you use the TemplatesSetting renderer, overriding widget templates
>   works the same as overriding any other template in your project. You
>   can’t override built-in widget templates using the other built-in
>   renderers.

So we need to set our renderer in the `settings.py` file:

```
FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting'
```

But if we only do that, we'd need to provide templates for *all* input elements. According to the docs:

> Using this renderer along with the built-in widget templates requires
>   [...] [adding] 'django.forms' in INSTALLED_APPS and at least one
>   engine with APP_DIRS=True.

So we add `django.forms` to `INSTALLED_APPS`. Now, in order to add our customization for, say, *text input elements*, we need to create the file `main/templates/django/forms/widgets/text.html` and add our custom HTML code there, like:

```
<input type="text" class="myclass" value="{{widget.value}}">
```

So, if we show a form in a template, that code will appear whenever a `CharField` need to be rendered, for example.

**But** all of this doesn't matter if you need a per-field level of control, for example if each field needs a different class. In that case, you should combine what I wrote with [django-widget-tweaks](https://github.com/kmike/django-widget-tweaks) so you can have more flexible widget customization.

Comment: Awesome answer; how would I style all error messages with the class `custom-error`? Are the error messages a "widget"? I actually don't need this since I can style the error by manually injecting the `field.errors`, but I'm curious if this is possible in an easy way by building a template.

Comment: template location above updated as per Anna Thomas's answer

Answer (score 8):

Continuing from José Tomás Tocino's answer above, In Django 1.11 I found that my directory structure needed to be:

main/templates/django/forms/widgets/text.html

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but this should probably be a comment or an edit. I realize that you're a new user.

Comment: @GregSchmit You're right, I tried to comment but didn't have the rep. I figured some sort of comment (to hopefully help the next person) was better than none at all.Thanks for not down voting me